# how to disable click event on marker after single click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After a single click on a marker, I'd like to:

1. Disable click event on the map
2. Wait 5 seconds
3. Re-enable click event on the map 
   I m using ajax as well as setInterval for 3 seconds
   This is my code:

   details = new google.maps.LatLng(18.60301515,73.79623622);
   bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow , details);

   function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, description) {

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function() {
       var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();

       geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': description }, function (results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               if (results[1]) {
                   var location1=results[1].formatted_address;
                   // set content to marker at click event
                   infoWindow.setContent('Location:'+location1+'<br>');
               }
           }
       });
       infoWindow.open(map, marker);
   });
   ```

   }

Thanks

Comment: Down vote. duplicate of other answer of the same user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

JavaScript

```
details = new google.maps.LatLng(18.60301515,73.79623622);
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow , details);  
var allowClick = true;

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, description) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function() {
    if(allowClick) {
      allowClick = false;

      var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': description }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[1]) {
            var location1=results[1].formatted_address;    
            infoWindow.setContent('Location:'+location1+'<br>');
          }
        }
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      setTimeout(function() { allowClick = true; }, 5000);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i use your code click disable n enable problm is solved but location is not update after changing the latitude n longitude. address also must change after changing points please help

Comment: @user5209761 That sounds like a different problem? If so, post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag (Global Value). and a Settimer to change the value of the flag after 5 second.

```
details = new google.maps.LatLng(18.60301515,73.79623622);
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow , details);  
 var flag_timer=true;
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, description) {

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function() {
         if(flag_timer===true){
         var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();

         geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': description }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                   var location1=results[1].formatted_address;    
         infoWindow.setContent('Location:'+location1+'<br>');      // set content to marker at click event


                }
            }
        });
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         flag_timer=false;
        setTimeout(function() { flag_timer = true; }, 5000);
     }
  });


}
```

Comment: i use your code click disable n enable problm is solved but location is not update after changing the latitude n longitude. address also must change after changing points please help

Comment: @user5209761can u please show the full code? I don't see anything related to updating the address?

Comment: @Arg0n As soon as i saw the question i think of this idea and make it available. After posting only i saw your code.